# Not able to include folder for C compilation

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

Everything compile if the C is in outer folder, but when lib.c is in [lib] folder, it gives an error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/lib.o', needed by 'run'.  Stop.`

How should the makefile be corrected to make sure the compilation is successful?
What is the correct way to emend the makefile?

The tree is such:

```
 ├── inc
 │   └── main.h
 ├── lib
 │   └── lib.c
 ├── main.c
 ├── main_functions.sh
 ├── Makefile
 └── test_usages.c
```

The makefile:

```
# IDIR =../include \
This is a makefile \

IDIR =./inc
CC=gcc

ODIR=obj
# LIB_SRC_DIR =./lib
LDIR =./lib 
CFLAGS=-I $(IDIR) $(LDIR)   ## added $(LDIR)

# header files required
_DEPS = *.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_DEP_LIB = *.c                                  ##
DEPS_LIB = $(patsubst %,$(LDIR)/%,$(_DEP_LIB))  ##

_OBJ = lib.o main.o test_usages.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

 $(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS) $(DEPS_LIB)       ## added $(DEPS_LIB)
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 

 #%.o: %.c
 #      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $(input) -o $(output)

 # make commands options: make <options>, e.g. make hello_make  
 # executable name
 hello_make: $(OBJ)
     gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

 run: $(OBJ)
     gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
     echo "=========================================================="
     ./run
     echo "=========================================================="

 .PHONY: clean

 clean:
     echo "cleaning ...." $(ODIR)/*.o
     rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~ ./*.exe
```

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: With `CFLAGS=-I $(IDIR) $(LDIR)` you make `CFLAGS` equal to `-I ./inc ./lib`. The second option (`./lib`) isn't valid. Did you want to add `-I ./lib`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You did that as a comment, because it is not addressing the main problem, correct? Or could it possibly fix everything?

Comment: Did you try rubber ducking? I.e. explain to yourself every detail of every line in your make file. It is part of  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ (which I think can just as well be applied to `make` as to any other language).

Comment: Well it seems to be the root cause of the error message you show (which I have to admit I didn't really read before now :))

Comment: how would you emend the make file to include the c codes in ./lib/ just as described in the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some quirks in your `Makefile`, but here is how I got it to work:

1. Remove trailing blank in the line `LDIR =./lib`
2. Insert `VPATH=$(LDIR)` at some convenient place

Now `make -n run` shows (but doesn't run) all expected command lines:

```
gcc -c -o obj/lib.o ./lib/lib.c -I ./inc ./lib
gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I ./inc ./lib
gcc -c -o obj/test_usages.o test_usages.c -I ./inc ./lib
gcc -o run obj/lib.o obj/main.o obj/test_usages.o -I ./inc ./lib
echo "=========================================================="
./run
echo "=========================================================="
```

BTW, you could use these options to debug your `Makefile`:

`make -npr run` print all variables, rules and so on, but not the built-ins.

`make -nd run` print all decisions, a lot of them.

Comment: `VPATH` is the perfect answer. Thank you, @the busybee